# Javascript change class onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im just trying to get to grips with javascript / ajax / jQuery so Im building a ticket system for my website.

Anyway, I have a table at the top of the page;

```
    <table align="center" class="thinline" width="600" border="1" cellpadding="2" bordercolor="black">
    <tr class="subtopic" style="font-size: 15px;">
        <td><a onClick="javascript: ShowNewTickets()">New Tickets</a></td>
        <td><a onClick="javascript: ShowYourTickets()">Your Tickets</a></td>
        <td><a onClick="javascript: ShowPuplicTickets()">Public Tickets</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the page loads I want "New Tickets" to have the class "selected". If they hover the mouse over any of the unselected menus then it has a highlighted effect. Once they click onto another link the "selected" class will be removed from the other TD and added to the new TD.

I have tryed onmouseover and onmouseout to do the highlight effect but it messes up when it comes to the link which is already highlighted.

I have also tryed,

```
    $('.off').live('mouseenter', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected') == false) {
        $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('highlighted');
    }
});
```

But that then keeps the TD highlighted.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You could create a color change on hover with CSS only. Also, your question does not seem to fit the title. Anyways: Whenever you leave an element, you have to remove the class `highlighted`.

Comment: Yeah, it would be better solved with CSS, considering the fact that you are using `a` elements. The `:hover` selector will work on all browsers (even IE6).

Comment: [It's that easy](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/FzjAP/).

Comment: Ahh thank you, I can use the javascript to remove the element aswell to stop the hightlight happening to the already hightlighed link?

Comment: @BradleyRoberts If you don't want the highlighting effect to be applied to the selected element, then [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/wTasG/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sergio Tulentsev mentioned, you should use the `:hover` pseudo class to handle the highlight effect. To handle the "selected" class, you could do something like this:

```
$('.subtopic').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    $('.subtopic a').removeClass('selected'); // remove the class from all the links
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // add it to the clicked link
}
```

Note that I am using the new jquery function [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of .click, .live or .delegate. The way .on() works, you will make sure you only bind events to the links in the .subtopic row. Using .on() also guarantees your events will still fire when adding new links dynamically to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I will have a attempt at this now!

Comment: @BradleyRoberts Hm, I just saw that I might be using the wrong class names. I see you're using highlighted and off as well, so you might need to switch class names around. 

jQuery code is mostly pretty readable, so I hope my example will suffice.

Comment: I have changed it a little. The css isnt anything set in stone Im just trying to get everything looking nice first :P I changed the a into td as the a even with padding wasnt filling the area needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`:hover` pseudo-class](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

It will handle mouse over/out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), it does what the name suggests.

Comment: ah yeah this looks like it will do the job :)!
Thank you.