# Change td class on click with javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

tried to apply this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688636/javascript-change-class-onclick) to make change the class of the cells in my table on click, yet it doesn't work :(

```
$('td.link').click(function() {
$('td.button_active').removeClass('button_active');
$('td.link').addClass('button');
$(this).removeClass('button');
$(this).addClass('button_active')
})
```

My example code in jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/64QpR/135/)..

Could someone take a short look and point what to change?

I am trying to make font red and change background image of clicked cell, other cells leaving with (or returning to) grey font and default backround image.

Thank you in advance!

Valdas

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/2TYyC/ and in your fiddle you are ussing mootools instead of jQuery.

Comment: in your fiddle you haven't added jQuery. Add jQuery and it'll work

Comment: It is working check http://jsfiddle.net/64QpR/138/,and You did not include  Jquery

Comment: Thank you, it works! In jsfiddle.. yet it still doesn't work on [my website](http://www.verslomonitorius.lt).. :(

Comment: Could someone check the code on my website (link in previous comment)?

Comment: Got it. I had to wrap my code when pasting to webpage ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've included MooTools instead of jQuery ;)

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64QpR/137/). It works when using jquery...

```
$('td.link').click(function() {
    $('td.button_active').removeClass('button_active');
    $('td.link').addClass('button');
    $(this).removeClass('button');
    $(this).addClass('button_active')
});
```

**Edit**

Here you go, a proper version. What I've done: put buttons inside the table cell (instead of transforming table cells into buttons), used an `active` class for the active button (instead of copying the button css to the `active_button` class), and altered the javascript a bit (less lines = nice :))

[**Check it out here** (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/64QpR/145/)

And the relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="link button active">Link One</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="link button">Link Two</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="link button">Link Three</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="link button">Link Four</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 113px;
    height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(http://www.verslomonitorius.lt/uploads/2/1/9/2/21922640/vm_button.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 138px 33px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    font: 16px/30px 'Ubuntu';
    color: #737373;
}

.active {
    background-image: url(http://www.verslomonitorius.lt/uploads/2/1/9/2/21922640/vm_button_active.svg);
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: default
}

.button:not(.active):hover {
    background-image: url(http://www.verslomonitorius.lt/uploads/2/1/9/2/21922640/vm_button_hover.svg);
    color: #000000;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('a.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

*Note: In a live version, don't forget to wrap your javascript in a $.ready or closure*

Comment: Why not add `button` to every <td> ? So you don't have to add it anymore with jquery. First <td> would become: `<td class="link button button_active">Link One</td>` and you can remove the unnecessary lines 3 and 4 in your code. I don't get why you would remove and add `button` as they all still remain buttons..

Comment: Because he didn't asked ;) But you are totally right, I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you Giorgio for edited code and for reminding to wrap te code :)

Comment: yw ;) btw: I included the wrong js snippet before, fixed that. Included fiddle also works like it should

Answer (score 0):

Be more accurate with libraries defined in jsfiddle. Here is [what you need.](http://jsfiddle.net/64QpR/135/)

```
$('td.link').click(function() {
    $('td.button_active').each(function(index) {
        $(this).removeClass('button_active');
    });
    $('td.link').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('button')
    });
    $(this).removeClass('button');
    $(this).addClass('button_active')
})
```